# Some integral inequality question with convexity

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a convex and integrable function such that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) - x$ exists and is finite. I am also given the fact that $\int_{0}^1f(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}$. I have to show that for any $n$ a natural number, $\int_{0}^1x^nf(x)dx \le \frac{1}{n+2}$.

I thought that the easiest way would be to show that $f(x)\le x$ for every $x$ in between $0$ and $1$, but I have no clue how should I use the fact that $f(x) - x$ has a limit at $+\infty$.

Comment: Do you know the property of "increasing slopes" of a convex function? Basically, the fact that $f(x)-x$ has a limit at $+\infty$ tells you something about the "asymptotic" slope of $f$ at infinity, which constrains its slops between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: unfortunatly $|x-1|$ contradicts your hope ! 
$f$ has an asymptote of slope 1, $\int_0^1f=\frac12$ and of course is not $\leq x$

Comment: In fact, there is no majoration of $f$.
take for example : $f(0)=N$, $f(1/N)=0$, $f=0$ in $[1/N,1]$ and finally $f=x$ for $x>1$. (of course $f$ affine "by parts")